# Why some of the local variables are not listed in the corresponding stack frame when inspected using GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, local-variables, callstack

I have a piece of code in C as shown below-

In a .c file-

```
1    custom_data_type2 myFunction1(custom_data_type1 a, custom_data_type2 b)
2    {
3        int c=foo();
4        custom_data_type3 t;
5        check_for_ir_path();
6        ...
7        ...
8    }
9
10    custom_data_type4 myFunction2(custom_data_type3 c, const void* d)
11    {
12        custom_data_type4 e;
13        struct custom_data_type5 f;
14        check_for_ir_path();
15        ...
16        temp = myFunction1(...);
17        return temp;
18    }
```

In a header file-

```
1    void CRASH_DUMP(int *i)
2     __attribute__((noinline));
3    
4    #define INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK    3
5    
6    #define check_for_ir_path() { \
7        if (checkfunc1() && !checkfunc2()) { \
8            int sv = INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK; \
9            ...
10            CRASH_DUMP(&sv);\
11        }\
12    }\
```

In an unknown scenario, there is a crash.
After processing the core dump using GDB, we get the call stack like -

```
#0  0x00007ffa589d9619 in myFunction1 [...] 
(custom_data_type1=0x8080808080808080, custom_data_type2=0x7ff9d77f76b8) at ../xxx/yyy/zzz.c:5

        sv = 32761

        t = <optimized out>



#1  0x00007ffa589d8f91 in myFunction2 [...]

(custom_data_type3=<optimized out>, d=0x7ff9d77f7748) at ../xxx/yyy/zzz.c:16

        sv = 167937677

        f = {

          ...

        }
```

---

If you see the function, `myFunction1` there are three local variables- `c`, `t`, `sv` (defined as part of macro definition). However, in the backtrace, in the frame 0, we see only two local variables - `t` and `sv`. And i dont see the variable `c` being listed.

Same is the case, in the function `myFunction2`, there are three local variables - `e`, `f`, `sv`(defined as part of macro definition). However, from the backtrace, in the frame 1, we see only two local variables - `f` and `sv`. And i dont see the variable `e` being listed.

Why is the behavior like this?

Any non-static variable declared inside the function, should be put on the callstack during execution and which should have been listed in the backtrace full, isn't it? However, some of the local variables are missing in the backtrace. Could someone provide an explanation?

Comment: "t = <optimized out>" is a hint that your code is compiled with optimizations turned on. After the compiler has optimized your code, it can remove your variables and greatly re-organize your code.

Comment: So if not on the stack, where else does the local variable be stored!?

Comment: @nos: much appreciated. So as part of optimisation, compiler would have not allocated storage for the variable `c` on the function stack. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: A variable doesn't have to be stored. The compiler has to do whatever it takes to make your program produce the result it needs to produce according to the standard. If the compiler manages to build executable code with two variables instead of three, it has every right to do that.

Comment: The most likely location for a local variable that isn't on the stack is in a CPU register. Another possibility (perhaps less likely these days) is an FPU register. Unless your debugger is clever enough to spot the usage of register variables, it isn't going to be able to print their values.

Comment: @Tim Randall: Oh... Yeah. That makes sense for the part- where else out could stored. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Objects local to a C function often do not appear on the stack because optimization during compilation often makes it unnecessary to store objects on the stack. In general, while an implementation of the C abstract machine may be viewed as storing objects to local to a function on the stack, the actual implementation on a real processor after compilation and optimization may be very different. In particular:

- An object local to a function may be created and used only inside a processor register. When there are enough processor registers to hold a function’s local objects, or some of them, there is no point in writing them to memory, so optimized code will not do so.
- Optimization may eliminate a local object completely or fold it into other values. For example, given `void foo(int x) { int t = 10; bar(x+2*t); … }`, the compiler may merely generate code that adds an immediate value of 20 to `x`, with the result that neither 10 nor any other instantiation of `t` ever appears on stack, in a register, or even in the immediate operand of an instruction. It simply does not exist in the generated code because there was no need for it.
- An object local to a function may appear on the stack at one point during a function’s code but not at others. And the places it appears may differ from place to place in the code. For example, with `{ int t = x*x; … bar(t); … t = x/3; … bar(t); … }`, the compiler may decide to stash the first value of `t` in one place on the stack. But the second value assigned to `t` is effectively a separate lifetime, and the compiler may stash it in another place on the stack (or not at all, per the above). In a good implementation, the debugger may be aware of these different places and display the stored value of `t` while the program counter is in a matching section of code. And, while the program counter is not in a matching section of code, `t` may effectively not exist, and the debugger could report it is optimized out at that point.